# tracking application , getting up time

Tags: c#

how will i get the running time of an application?

I have 2 separate programs that i would like to join.

First Project is a windows form project that gets the up time of the process

```
        txtFrequency.Text = Stopwatch.Frequency.ToString();
        txtNsPerTick.Text = (1000000000 / Stopwatch.Frequency).ToString();
        txtIsHighRes.Text = Stopwatch.IsHighResolution.ToString();
        btnStart.Enabled = false;
        btnStop.Enabled = true;
        txtElapsed1.Clear();
        txtElapsed2.Clear();
        txtElapsed3.Clear();
        StopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        TotalWatch.Start();
        StartTime = DateTime.Now;
```

It handles on a button click, and it only works for that process,

The Second Project is a windows forms project that gets  all running processes

```
Process[] process = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process prs in process)
{
     listBox1.Items.Add(prs.ProcessName + "         (" + prs.PrivateMemorySize64.ToString() + ")");
}
```

My plan is to have the elapsed time of the processes that gets listed in the list box?

Is this possible? and how?

There's no precise format in how it must display the run time of that program, could be a message box it doesn't matter for now. How do I change my timer so that it gets the time of other running programs?

Comment: If you use a Stopwatch and instantiate it during the `Form` construction, you can use the ticks. You need to make that stopwatch a static property of `Form`

Comment: james, you can always edit your own questions or answers. There's no need to answer your own question as an attempt to comment it.